# Simple merge of the js files caused errors and jquery being undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge

I'm dealing with a pure js front-end here and tried to use [Juicer](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool) today to compress the javascripts.
It worked fine thought without minification since there are tons of errors in libraries I use found by JsLint the validator of which is essential to pass in order to have files minimized.
I left it as is since that would be cool to have at least merging working but it seems not to be the case.
Though eventually all the files were indeed merged into one, app stopped working since jquery is considered undefined. In the file is stays on the first place though.

What could be the possible reason for such a strange behavior? Thanks a lot in advance for your answer!

UPD Here is a [link to the merged file](http://gist.github.com/874368)

Comment: There are tons of errors in the libraries? You mean real errors or just jslint errors?

Comment: Were they merged in the same order that that are normally included? Could you post the javascripts in question or link to the page?

Comment: They are jslint "errors". Order is exactly the same and here is the file: https://gist.github.com/874368. The error which I get including this file only is "vendor.min.js:4147Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL", which I really don't get, since it's an error on the comment. If I include any other js files - they cannot recognize jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only want to merge them and not minify them, maybe try merging them manually. It's just:

```
cat file1.js file2.js file3.js > all.js
```

It's the same for CSS, no fancy merging is needed.

For minification of JavaScript I recommend [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) because it tends to not break code unlike some other tools. UglifyJS is used by jQuery.

When you merge the JavaScript files by simple concatenation what's important is the order of the files to not break dependencies. Another thing that sometimes causes problems are missing semicolons (those can break the code after minification) or missing newlines at the end of the files.

Comment: Iloveyouiloveyouiloveyou. UglifyJS is the best thing ever. Oh my heck. You just saved me hours of manual work.

Comment: @tylermwashburn: If you uglify it too much, use the [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). ;)

Comment: Cat is indeed enough for me at the moment if it only supported the way to fetch the list of files to merge from some other file listing them in a well structured list. I have quite many dependencies so listing them one after another is not convenient. I've tried to google but cannot find something like -f vendor.txt to do the job. Probably you could recommend a way? Later I will certainly check Uglify with it's api which looks handy.